# How to use an User Agent string with an API?

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley, user-agent

I'm working with an API using volley Android library.

I have to pass the user agent of the Android Device as an parameter in the API URL.

User Agent string has spaces and some characters which are not allowed in a URL.

How can I convert the User Agent string to such that I can use it with an API.

I'm using the below solution to get the user agent but don't have any idea how to further modify the string to use it with API.

```
   private static String GetUserAgent(Context act) {
        String userAgent = new WebView(act).getSettings().getUserAgentString();

        return userAgent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode it using [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

```
 URLEncoder.encode(userAgent);
```

> The space character "   " is converted into a plus sign "+".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But do you think that a + sign would work fine with the API. Also, there are other symbols also hence I require to convert them also.

Comment: @RajeshK this will fix all reelevant chracters